# How to convert Year-Month 'Character Value' into 'Date Value' in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to change the Character value into Date value to make the data reactive to dateRangeinput in R shiny. However, I believe that the Dates should be in Date format or value, not in Character or String value.

I am having a problem to convert them. Below is the code

```
CompletedProject$EndDate <- ymd(substring(CompletedProject$EndDate, first = 1, last = 10))

CompletedProject$EndDate <- format(as.Date(CompletedProject$EndDate), "%Y-%m")

CompletedProject_monthly <- subset(CompletedProject_monthly, CompletedProject_monthly$EndDate >= input$IMdaterange[1] & CompletedProject_monthly$EndDate <= input$IMdaterange[2])

> class(CompletedProject$EndDate)
[1] "character"
```

I have tried as.Date function, but it didn't work.

I can do it with year month day format easily, but year month format is harder.
I need the date format as year-month.

Appreciate for help experts!!

Comment: The [`anytime`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/anytime.pdf) package is handy for this kind of thing.

Comment: The `format()` function always returns a character vector when formatting a date. If you want the field to be a date field then just stick with `as.Date(CompletedProject$EndDate)` If the text in `CompletedProject$EndDate` is already in `%Y-%m` format and you need to interpret as a date, use `as.Date(paste0(CompletedProject$EndDate,"-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")`